# Delay in Active Directory user creation when using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, user-accounts

I am creating accounts and setting properties on them using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in .NET 4.5. One of the requirements is that the group membership (including Primary Group) be copied from a template account. The code includes the following:

```
foreach (var group in userPrincipal.GetGroups()) {
    var groupPrincipal = (GroupPrincipal) @group;

    if (groupPrincipal.Sid != templatePrimaryGroup.Sid) {
        groupPrincipal.Members.Remove(userPrincipal);
        groupPrincipal.Save();
    }
}
```

This works about 90% of the time. The rest of the time, it fails with:

> `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException was
>   unhandled   HResult=-2147016656   Message=There is no such object on
>   the server.`
>
> Source=System.DirectoryServices   ErrorCode=-2147016656 
>   ExtendedError=8333   ExtendedErrorMessage=0000208D: NameErr:
>   DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
>   'OU=Whatever,DC=domain,DC=local`

on the `GetGroups` call. My guess is that there is a race condition of some sort with the user not being fully created before I next go to access it. I know from diagnostic logging that I am going against the same domain controller each time (it's using the same `PrincipalContext` so that matches my expectation) so it's not a replication issue.

Is my guess accurate? Is there a good way to handle this? I could just throw in a `Sleep` but that seems like a cop-out at best and fragile at worst. So what is the right thing to do?

Comment: Does the user account get created?  If you're unsure, set a break point at GetGroups() and check. If the account is created just loop until you can query it's primary group, then break and continue.

Comment: It does get created, yes. So basically you're suggesting I try GetGroups and if it fails, wait a short time, then try again, etc.? That's a little yucky but slightly better I guess than just a fixed delay. If that's your answer please make an answer so I can accept if I decide to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
        int maxWait = 120;
        int cnt = 0;
        bool usable = false;

        while (usable == false && cnt < maxWait)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var group in userPrincipal.GetGroups())
                {
                    var groupPrincipal = (GroupPrincipal)@group;

                    if (groupPrincipal.Sid != templatePrimaryGroup.Sid)
                    {
                        groupPrincipal.Members.Remove(userPrincipal);
                        groupPrincipal.Save();
                    }
                }
                usable = true;
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
        if (usable)
            //All okay
            ;
        else
            //Do something
            ;
```

This way you can try for "a while". If it works good, if not do something like log an error, so you can run a fix-it script later.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing - close enough that it works as an answer. I'm unhappy that I'm having to do something like this but it does get past the issue.

Comment: Does the DC in question log events when the function fails?  Possibly the local AD cache is not being written quickly enough to the DC...  Ensure that the DC and client time is synced, and after a failed call, look at the WhenCreated attribute in AD.

Comment: To answer your questions: There's nothing interesting in the DC event logs. Time sync is good. Given the usage volume of the tool in question, I don't think the performance hit of the looping is too bad, so I think I'm going to let it go for now unless I find more time to focus on this specific issue. Thanks!